# Convert numbers in string format to integer format (Java)

Tags: java, integer, buffer, filereader, parseint

I have a litte problem:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Ninteri {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader f = new FileReader("/Users/MyUser/Desktop/reader.txt");

        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);

        String s;
        int x;

        while (true) {
            s = b.readLine();
            if (s == null) {
                break;
            }

            x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at stream.Ninteri.main(Ninteri.java:22)
```

Comment: What does the file look like?  Are the numbers separated by a space or newline?

Comment: You can't turn the entire string "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" into a single int. You need to split it on whitespaces and then parse the individual elements of that array

Comment: If s is the entire line, you need to break it up with String[] snums = s.split("\\s");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it is clear that the first line in your file is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` which is not a number string itself; rather, a string containing number strings. First, you need to split this line into an array of number strings and then you need to iterate the array and parse each element in the array into `int`.

```
while (true) {
    s = b.readLine();
    if (s == null) {
        break;
    }
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+");// Split the line on space(s)
    for (String num : arr) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(num);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 isn't a single number so it cannot be represented by an Integer.

Use a for block on the string array resulting from split to convert each of them individually.

```
for(String a: s.split("\\s")) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```